# AutoComplete Doesn't Seem to Work on Ajax Masked Edit Control

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am looking to use the Ajax MaskedEditControlExtender to create a masked input field for entry of a Zip Code. I have the masked part working fine but I can't seem to get the AutoComplete feature to work. My understanding is when I set AutoComplete to "true" and the AutoCompleteValue to "0" the extender should fill in any mask characters that the user did not fill with the "0".

When I tab out of the input element it simply leaves the characters that I typed and does not fill the remaining places with the zero "0"

Am I not understanding this feature correctly or am I not implementing this feature correctly?

Any insight would be truly appreciated.

Here is my html:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="AjaxTest._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="MaskedEditStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipCode" runat="server" Text = "" CssClass="MaskedEditDisplay"  />
            <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtZipCodeExtender" 
                runat="server" 
                TargetControlID="txtZipCode" 
                AcceptNegative="None"
                InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                Mask="99999-9999"
                OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"   
                OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" 
                AutoComplete="true" 
                AutoCompleteValue="0"
                />
            <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtZipCode" 
                ControlExtender="txtZipCodeExtender" 
                Display="Dynamic" 
                TooltipMessage="Enter a valid Zip Code" 
                IsValidEmpty="false"  
                EmptyValueMessage="Zip Code is Required" 
                InvalidValueMessage="Invalid Zip Code"
                CssClass="MaskedEditMsg" 
                SetFocusOnError="true"  
                />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```